# Showing by Hand that $H^1(0)=0 , H^1(-p)=0$ in $\mathbb{C}$ , Mittag-Leffer Problems in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}/L$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, laurent-series

I am trying to show by hand, without using the *Riemann-Roch Theorem*, that in $\Bbb C_{\infty}$ we will have that $H^1(0)=0$ and $H^1(-p)=0$, but I am having some trouble constructing the functions that are related to the *Laurent series*, so I guess this is more a complex analysis question that if I have a *Laurent series* that is like $a_n\frac{1}{z^n}+\ldots+a_0\frac{1}{z}$ at point $p$ and $b_k\frac{1}{z^k}+\ldots+b_m\frac{1}{z^m}$ at point $q$ how can i construct a meromorphic function that will have these laurent series at these points and be holomorphic elesewhere and so on ? I am bit confused on how to make things work.

Also I am trying do another exercise that it's kind of the same idea that I cant find the desired functions, it goes like this

> Let $X$ be the complex torus, fix a finite number of points $p_i \in X$ with local coordinate $z_i$ at $p_i$, consider the laurent divisor $Z=\sum\limits_{i}c_iz_i^{-1}.p_i$, show that $Z=\alpha_0(f)$ for some global meromorphic function $f$ iff $\sum\limits_i c_i=0$.

I was able to do the first implication using the residue theorem applied to $fdz$, now for the second one I am trying to construct the function by taking other points $q_j$ such that $\sum\limits_j q_j - \sum\limits_i p_i \in \Bbb Z$ and then using the ratio of theta-translated functions $\frac{\prod_j \vartheta^{q_j}(z)}{\prod_i \vartheta^{p_i}(z)}$ but I dont know how I am going to make the functions get the residue $c_i$ at the point $p_i$, I have to change something from that function but I dont know what.

So any tips or help would be aprecciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two ways to construct the meromorphic functions on $\Bbb{C}/L$ : either from its zeros/poles $f(z)=c\prod_{j=1}^J \frac{\theta(z-a_j;\tau)}{\theta(z-b_j;\tau)}$ with $\sum_j a_j-b_j=0$ or from its poles $g(z)=D+\sum_{l\in L} (\sum_{j=1}^J \frac{A_j}{z-a_j-l}+\frac{A_j 1_{l\ne 0}}l)+(\sum_{j=1}^I \frac{B_j}{(z-b_j-l)^2}-\frac{B_j 1_{l\ne 0}}{l^2})+\sum_{j=1}^K \frac{C_j}{(z-c_j-l)^{e_j+3}}$ with $\sum_j A_j=0$